# android emulator dev menu doesn't come up in react native

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04

I hit `cmd + m` and nothing happens
also tried combinations with `ctrl` `alt` and `shift`.
nothing.

hitting `r` twice works, invokes a refresh.

Any ideas how to go about it?

**spec**
os: `ubuntu 16.04`
RN version: `0.39.2`
Emulator device: `Nexus 6`
Emulator device OS: `Android 6.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In console type `adb shell` and `input keyevent 82`